# How to maintain dropdown open when changing child state in recursive component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion

The data is an object array with nested object arrays. The items are displayed in a nested fashion using a recursive component and the checked state is changed using a recursive function. In each rendered component these is a state which controls whether or not its children should be displayed. My issue is that when I change the state of a child item the dropdown closes.

Here is a simplified version of the code.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const beData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    label: "fruit",
    checked: false,
    children: [
      { id: 23, label: "apples", checked: false },
      { id: 21, label: "orange", checked: false }
    ]
  },
  { id: 32, label: "dairy", checked: false }
];

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(beData);
  const recursiveMap = (data, key) => {
    return data.map((i) => {
      let result = { ...i };
      if (i.id === key) result = { ...i, checked: !i.checked };
      if (i.children && i.children.length) result.children = recursiveMap(i.children, key);
      return result;
    });
  };

  const handleClick = (key) => setData(recursiveMap(data, key));

  const RecursiveComponent = ({ data }) => {
    const [showChildren, setShowChildren] = useState(false);
    return (
      <div>
        <label style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
          <button onClick={() => setShowChildren(!showChildren)} type="button">
            v
          </button>
          <input
            checked={data.checked}
            onChange={() => handleClick(data.id)}
            type="checkbox"
          ></input>
          <p>{data.label}</p>
        </label>

        <div style={{ paddingLeft: "30px" }}>
          {data.children && data.children.length > 0 &&
            showChildren &&
            data.children.map((data2) => <RecursiveComponent data={data2} key={data2.id} />)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map((data) => (
        <RecursiveComponent data={data} key={data.id} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Is this what you want? https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-hertz-dlunl

Comment: Yes that is exactly it. Thank you!